# How to create 2-D arrays in systemverilog and call the elements in this array later?

Tags: fpga, vga

I am writing a little game on FPGA in System Verilog and I want to show some small pictures through VGA display. My picture size is 35px X 20px. I converted the picture into three separate arrays (R, G and B values)by using Matlab. I do not know how I can create similar arrays in System Verilog and then call elements in them later. Below is my current code where I have made white dots and red dots. I want to replace these dots with the pictures I mentioned above. Thanks!

```
begin:RGB_Display                   
      if (missile_On == 1'b1)         
      begin 
            Red = 8'h00;
        Green = 8'hff;
        Blue = 8'h3f;
    end  
      else if (ourMissileOn == 1'b1)
      begin
            Red = 8'hff;
        Green = 8'hff;
        Blue = 8'h00;
    end 
    else if ((ball_on == 1'b1)) 
    begin 
        Red = 8'hff;
        Green = 8'hff;
        Blue = 8'hff;
    end  
        else if ((enemyAppear == 1'b1)) 
    begin 
        Red = 8'hff;
        Green = 8'h00;
        Blue = 8'h2f;
    end  
    else 
    begin 
        Red = 8'h3f; 
        Green = 8'h00;
        Blue = 8'h3f; //- DrawX[9:3];
    end      
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store color information in 24 bit register as

24'hRRGGBB, (RR - Red, GG - Green, BB - Blue) - one pixel

35px x 20px = 700px, 700 * 3 bytes = 2100 bytes

First 35 * 3 = 105 bytes of memory is a first row of image.

Second 35 * 3 = 105 bytes of memory is a second row of image.

....

You can use FPGA Block RAM.